# Vagrant provision current physical machine

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I've a Vagrant configuration that works perfectly on a VM for me, and I want to move that setup to the current physical machine that I've.

Is there any providers that allows to run a Vagrantfile in the current physical machine? It's a ubuntu (same version configured as a box in the Vagrantfile).

Comment: What tool do you use for provisioning?

Comment: I'm using puppet, it's generated with puphpet. And the provider is virtualbox

Comment: I was thinking in create a ssh provider or use https://github.com/tknerr/vagrant-managed-servers and connect to localhost. not sure if it will work

Comment: I am not familiar with Puppet, but I would expect that you could tweak your provision so that it runs on your local machine. Or at least that's how I would try to go with Ansible

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take the puphpet directory (including the puppet directory with modules and manifest) and run puppet from there (assuming you have puppet installed locally)

The thing with puphpet is that there's lot of vagrant specific (like assuming you will have a /vagrant directory)

so lets do:

- change the `puppet/sites.pp` to point to your yaml local files
- change the `puppet/hiera.yaml` to point the location of the config.yam file

and then you can run puppet like

```
puppet apply --verbose --hiera_config puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml --parser future --modulepath 'puphpet/puppet/modules' --detailed-exitcodes --manifestdir puphpet/puppet/manifests puphpet/puppet/site.pp
```

This is the command that vagrant would run so you can run it (be careful depending what you already have configured locally that there's no duplicate app and conflict)